# How to debug a remotely hosted WCF web service

Tags: wcf, debugging

I am new to WCF web service development and I can use some help.
I have a simple web service written in C# that I'm hosting on a remote server (it's hosted on IIS 5.1).
I've written a client application for that web service that I'm running on my workstation.I am able to connect to the service without any problems.
However, I would like to be able to debug the web service.I need to be able to step through the code, set breakpoints, etc.How do I achieve that from my local machine? I'm using Visual Studio 2010.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I see two possibilities:

1. **Local debugging**: For debugging, run your service on your local machine. If you want to run it on the local IIS, simply start a second instance if VS2010 and attach to the w3wp.exe process (menu Tools -> Attach to process)
2. **Remote Debugging**: You have to install and start the VS2010 remote debugger on the server. Start a second instance of VS2010 on your development box and connect to the remote debugger with menu Tools -> Attach to process.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) for more information about remote debugging with VS2010.